# Error when explicitly converting a template non-type parameter

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the code:

```
class Base{};
class Derived: public Base{};

template<Base& b> // references (and pointers) can be used as non-types
void f(){}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    // f(d); // Error, template type must match exactly
    f<(Base&)d>(); // Error here, why?!
}
```

I understand why the commented call fails: the template type must match exactly. I try however a cast in the second call, and get this error (gcc5.2):

> error: 'd' is not a valid template argument for type 'Base&' because it is not an object with external linkage

Same error if I make `Derived d;` global. clang is a bit more helpful, saying

> ... note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified
>         argument for template parameter 'b'

My question is: is the code above legal or not? If not, are there any reasons why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>*This answer assumes C++11 or higher*</sub>

Two issues here:

1) No derived-to-base conversion for non-type template parameter *[temp.arg.nontype]/p1*

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the
>   value of the constant expression **shall not refer to** (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>
> — a subobject (1.8),

2) The object's address should be available at compile time. Summarizing *[temp.arg.nontype]/p1* and *[expr.const]/p5* it follows that it should have [static storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration).

Put these two points together and you'll have that the following compiles

```
class Base{};
class Derived: public Base{};

template<Base& b> // references (and pointers) can be used as non-types
void f(){}

Base obj; // Static storage duration

int main()
{
    f<obj>();
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2badba848287ae4e)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

From [temp.arg.nontype]:

> A *template-argument* for a non-type *template-parameter* **shall be a converted constant expression** (5.20) of
>   the type of the *template-parameter*.

There are two issues here. First, `d` doesn't have linkage so you can't take a reference to it in a constant expression. That's an easy fix though:

```
Derived d;
int main() {
    f<d>(); // still an error
}
```

Now, we have another issue. We move onto the next sentence:

> For a non-type *template-parameter* of reference or pointer type, the
>   value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer type, shall not be the address of):
>   (1.1) — a subobject (1.8),

We're trying to take a reference is a subobject (a base class subobject) of `Derived`. That is explicitly disallowed, regardless of linkage.